# How to get "cron" support in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cron

Does self-hosted (non-Forge) Laravel have a cron system?  Or has this been supplanted by worker queues?

That is, in many PHP frameworks, there's a single cron file to run -- often named `cron.php`.  You're usually instructed to configure this script to run every 15 minutes (or some similar time) via a unix cron job.

```
1,15,30,45 * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/cron.php
```

Does Laravel have a similar system?  Googling about I've seen some mentions that [Forge has a solution for this](http://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-forge-scheduling-a-cron-job), and that older version of Laravel might have had a system, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer W/R/T Laravel 4.

Comment: Are you asking if in Laravel "`there's a single cron file to run`" or if Laravel enables you to "`configure this script to run every 15 minutes`"?

Comment: @Brian More the former than the later.  I'm want to know if Laravel  has a central cron system similar to other PHP frameworks, and if not what sort of support Laravel has for creating and managing cron jobs.

Comment: Do you feel Artisan, the command line utility for Laravel, isn't the right tool for the job? It's the only method I am aware of and given that cron jobs are usually commands or shell scripts, its sort of harmonious :)

Comment: @Brian Artisan makes sense as the command runner -- I was mainly looking for the mechanisms, if any, Laravel provides for abstracting unix's cron into a general system. The Indatus package provided what I was looking for there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can schedule artisan commands and make your own commands like so:

```
php artisan command:make cronCommand
```

Which will result in a `cronCommand.php` file in your `app/commands` directory

Then you make artisan aware of the command

Add `Artisan::add(new cronCommand);` to `app/start/artisan.php`

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Now you can see your new command via `php artisan list`

and schedule it via  `1,15,30,45 * * * * artisan cronCommand`

---

**Reference**

- [Laravel Commands - Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/commands)
- [Taylor Otwell - Building Artisan Commands](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGwnCWfzLRI&hd=1)
- [Dispatcher - Artisan Command Scheduler](https://github.com/Indatus/dispatcher)